# C++ return value of a function

Tags: c++, function

I came with a problem, and during the solution I got the following function:

```
bool interesting(int n){
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(sum(n+1, 0) < sum(n, 0)
            return true;
        }
}
```

This is, given a number n to verify if the sum(n+1,0) of the next number is smaller than the previous. However I wonder if the function is going to return true or false, since I have multiple i's to be looped.

Comment: This function (after fixing the missing parentheses) is going to return `true` or exhibit [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). There is no case where the function remains well-defined and returns false.

Comment: You miss a return at end.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum(int n, int m) { return -1; }
 
bool interesting(int n){

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if(sum(n+1, 0) < sum(n, 0))
        return true;
    }
  // miss return here
}

int main() {}
```

This might not compile. Even if it compiles it will yield an undefined behavior. For a function returning a bool all paths ways in the function should return a value.

> Warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths

[Try to compile the code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27int+sum(int+n,+int+m)+%7B+return+-1%3B+%7D%0A+%0Abool+interesting(int+n)%7B%0A%0Afor(int+i+%3D+1%3B+i+%3C%3D+n%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++if(sum(n%2B1,+0)+%3C+sum(n,+0))%0A++++++++return+true%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.633136094674555,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:32.726704701966504,l:%274%27,m:45.18716577540107,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:54.81283422459893,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.366863905325445,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Also, once that condition is met this function will exit with true. I think this is what you need:

```
int sum(int n, int m) { return -1; }
     
bool interesting(int n){
    bool result = true;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(!(sum(n+1, 0) < sum(n, 0)))
            result = false;
        }
     return result;
 }
```

Edit: I was wrong to assume that your code won’t compile. It happens that on some compilers it does compile but emits a warning

Comment: unsure about the last bit, good answer though

Comment: Note that some compilers  still compile without the return, they only emit a warning.
Example: G++ MinGW-W64 8.x.
In that case the actual returned value is undefined, though.

Comment: Instead of using the `!` operator, you could change the comparison to `>=`.  In this case, IMHO, changing the comparison would be more readable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews true; agreed

Comment: Even your own godbolt link shows the code compiling, however if you add the `-Werror` flag it will not.

Comment: You are right guys, my bad. I tried to edit the answer, feel free to edit to offer more details. Thank you for the comments

Comment: But, I wanted just with the code I provided to see what happens.